# Can’t seem to find the link to share the form. Also, when the form is embedded, there are two forms that appear

Tags: cognito-forms

So no options of a link-based share, only embeds? And when I copy paste the embed code, the form is displayed twice (have a look at the second screenshot). I made sure that the embed code was pasted only once.

[image: So no options of a link based share, only embeds? And when I copy paste the embed code, the form is displayed twice.. have a look at the second screenshot.]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

When helping you via the support ticket you submitted, we found the following. A 3rd party script is running on your site and causing the html code that places your Cognito Form on the page to be copied. The script is called "postacio-type-cleanup.js". You have three options to correct this on your page.

1. You can disable this script.
2. Move the Cognito embed code outside of the this div element `<div data-type-cleanup="true">`".
3. Change the statement inside of the div elemnet `data-type-cleanup="true"` to `data-type-cleanup="false"`.